# Web Part "Recent Checkins" in sharepoint not showing changes

Tags: git, sharepoint, tfs, checkin, changeset

I have connected a project to my TFS. When creating a team project I have also created a SharePoint site. Everything is working well except for the "Recent Checkins" web part which are not being displayed.

I am given the following error:

> TF10127: The path does not include a source control item. Type or select a different path.

I tried selecting the source from the change button available as mentioned in [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/33b1eb64-9adb-4a9c-aacf-4d8e57855f01/web-part-recent-checkins-in-sharepoint-project-site?forum=ApplicationInsights) but I am constantly being given the same error message.

Note: I am using a GIT repository, and the version of TFS is 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SharePoint integration with TFS does not support git. That webpart will not work with git.

Comment: Do you have a reference to your answer?

Comment: Nope, it just is. There has been no new investment in tyebSharePoint integration since 2010.

Comment: @Elle: Here is [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn641201.aspx) you seek. Scroll down to the bottom of the page and you'll find the note *"If you use Git for version control, check-in data is not available."* We're left with deletion of the Web Part as our only alternative.